# Laravel doesn't load style assets when using docker

Tags: php, laravel, docker

**Assets on fresh installation of Laravel 6 somewhy doesn't work with with docker.
When using `php artisan serve` everything works fine.**

So the problem is probably in my .yml file, either nginx or php-fpm and I can't see what I'm missing

```
  webserver:
    image: nginx:alpine
    container_name: webserver
    working_dir: /application
    volumes:
     - .:/application
     - ./docker/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    ports:
     - "8081:80"

  php-fpm:
    build: docker/php-fpm
    container_name: php-fpm
    working_dir: /application
    volumes:
      - ./laravel:/application
      - ./docker/php-fpm/php-ini-overrides.ini:/etc/php/7.2/fpm/conf.d/99-overrides.ini
```

Or maybe it's something else, point me to the right direction.

Comment: Please check your element in chrome, and post the error

Comment: Only styles don't work? Everything else is going well? what means the point in `.:/application` on webserver volumes? maybe should be `./:/application` (point with a slash = current directory) or looking at the volumes in php-fpm, I think you are trying to mount the application code in the `./laravel` directory to the `/application` directory inside the container, so maybe what you want is `./laravel:/application`

Comment: Yeah, just replaced `./:/application` with `./laravel:/application` and it works, still can't understand why application worked but not assets